# Android Crosswalk allow multiple windows bug(?)

Tags: java, android, crosswalk-runtime

I'm developing app with crosswalk and tinypass authorization in webview. But, when I turned multi-window mode on - by executing:

```
XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.SUPPORT_MULTIPLE_WINDOWS, true);
```

I was not able to open login window. Log messages:

```
E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(175)] GpuChannelHost::CreateViewCommandBuffer failed.
E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(226)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
```

But when I turned off mutli-window mode, dialog was successfully opened, but with another bug: when I finished registration and saw "You have access to the item" button, after click, activity with crosswalk was closed, because that button executed "self.close()" javascript command. With multiple windows all must be ok, because this closes only current window, but if window is only one, it closes activity. Maybe someone found some workaround?